# How to add My custom module in existing menu (Backend)

Tags: magento2, adminmenu

I have inserted one module in Magento Backend named "Importactualprice"!

It's coming as a new menu in admin backend!

I want that as submenu in Sales menu! **How to achieve this?**

[image]

my Menu.xml file code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../Magento/Backend/etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Backend_Importactualprice::parent" title="Importactualprice" module="Backend_Importactualprice" sortOrder="100" resource="Backend_Importactualprice::parent"/>
        <add id="Backend_Importactualprice::index" title="Importactualprice Index" module="Backend_Importactualprice" sortOrder="10" action="importactualprice/index" resource="Backend_Importactualprice::index" parent="Backend_Importactualprice::parent"/>

    </menu>
</config>
```

Comment: Paste your code for `menu.xml` and `system.xml`

Comment: i have added menu.xml code! right now i don't have system.xml

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to add below code in `menu.xml`

```
<menu>
   <add id="Backend_Importactualprice::parent"
   title="Importactualprice" 
   module="Backend_Importactualprice" sortOrder="100"
   resource="Magento_Sales::sales" parent="Magento_Sales::sales" />

    <add id="Backend_Importactualprice::index" 
     title="Importactualprice Index" 
     module="Backend_Importactualprice" sortOrder="10" 
     action="importactualprice/index"
     resource="Magento_Sales::manage" 
     parent="Backend_Importactualprice::parent"/>

</menu>
```

**Dont forget to clear cache after modify file.**

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Moazzam_AdminPage::egadmin"
             title="Eg Solution" parent="Magento_Sales::sales" module="Moazzam_AdminPage"
             sortOrder="10"
             resource="Moazzam_AdminPage::egadmin"
        />
        <add id="Moazzam_AdminPage::manage" title="Manage Admin Router"
             module="Moazzam_AdminPage" sortOrder="10" action="createadminpage/newpage"
             resource="Moazzam_AdminPage::manage" parent="Moazzam_AdminPage::egadmin"/>
    </menu>

</config>
```